# question on how to use sql server integrated service

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called book with, the attrbutes are booked_id, yearmon, and day_01....day_31. Now i need to unpivot the table and transform day_01...day_31 into rows, I have successed in doing that, but the problem is that my yearmon is a format of 200805 and i need to append a day to it based on day_01 or day_02 etc, so that i can create a new column with date information for example, if it is day_01, it looks like 20080501. Instead of writing huge query, does anyone how to use ssis to tranform it

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the Unpivot component and the Derived Column component to do what you need. Look into those and post back if they don't seem to do what you need.